# The whole div with icon should be clickable

Tags: html, css

I don't know how I can make the plus icon over the whole distance of the divs clickable. I can only make the plus is clickable. How can I divide the div full and place the plus to the right? 
How can I give the div full width but the plus in the bottom right place?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.br {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

.plus:hover {
  color: green;
}

.bg:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="plus br">
    <span>+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "whole distance of the divs"?

Comment: sorry, i mean full width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, try it;

```
<a href="#">
    <div style="text-align:right">
        +
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, damn, just so easy... Thank you so much! Probably I thought too complicated :)

Comment: :D .. glad to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="plus br">
            <span>+</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: It's again just the plus clickable, not the entire div

Comment: @azrm Okay, I thought the main div

Answer (score 0):

you set position `bottom:5px`  if you want div position according to `.bg` please use prance div in relative **please try i thing it's helpful**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  
  
.bg {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

 .br {
    background: #222 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}

.br{
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}

.plus:hover{
 color: green;
}

.bg:hover{
 color: green;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="bg">
        <div class="plus br">
          <span>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want clickable plush icon add in `<a> or <button>`

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp in an `anchor` tag and align the text in `div` carry the "+" right

```html
<a href="#">
    <div style="text-align:right">
        +
    </div>
</a>
```